# Ansible-Playbook: Failed to connect to the host via ssh: no such identity

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to run a playbook on some servers I am trying to setup with Ansible playbook. To do this I created a hosts file for dev inventories:

```
all:
  servers:
    hosts:
      my_server1:
      my_server2:
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_user: myremoteuser
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ private_key }}"
```

I populate the `private_key` from my vault like so:  `private_key: "{{vault_private_key | b64decode}}"`

`vault_private_key` is the base64 encoded private 2048 rsa key that I generated, and I can see that it correctly decodes in the error message like so:

```
   "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: no such identity: -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

I generated the ssh key with the following command:
`ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f myremoteuser_key -C myremoteuser`

When I ssh into `my_server1` or `2`, I can verify that `/home/myremoteuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` has the public key generated in there, which I verified by greping the public key text.

I can ssh via commandline. Is there something I am missing when attempting to set the private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite tell from your question -- can you confirm you are not confusing private key file *path* with private key file *contents*?

Are you writing the private key to disk?  If so, are you setting the permissions to 0600?  SSH won't read a private key file where the permissions are too broad.

I suspect you are running into an issue with permissions.

Why don't you just use a `template` task to populate the contents of your private key?  See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html

You can put a variable into your template file, `{{vault_private_key | b64decode}}`

Comment: I am trying to encrypt the private key file contents into the vault so that I can check this into source control. I am not writing the contents into a file at all after I decrypt and decode. Should I be? Can I just pass in the private key directly without creating a intermediate file?

Comment: As an example I can take the exact file I encrypted and encoded and connect to the server:
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/server_key myremoteuser@my_server1` where server_key file has the following permissions: -rw-------

Comment: I think you are correct, I need to set ansible_ssh_private_key_file to a file and then set `ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/server_key` after which I am able to ping.

Comment: That did it! What I needed to do was modify my `vars.yml` file to include ```private_key: "{{vault_private_key | b64decode}}"
private_key_file: ~/.ssh/server_key``` and then in my playbook:
```---
- hosts: localhost
...
    tasks:
    - tempfile:
        state: file
        suffix: pem
        register: temp_key
   - template:
        src:  templates/server_key.j2
        dest: "{{ private_key_file }}"
      vars:
        ssh_private_key: "{{ private_key }}"
```

if you can add in this to your answer, I will accept it. I had hoped that I didn't need to write it to a temp file.

Comment: You should not need to use a tempfile. You are right in not wanting to use a tempfile.  I've updated my answer.  Don't forget to set permissions on the resulting private key file!